# React - display specific content based on URL using useLocation

Tags: reactjs, react-router, url-parameters, dynamic-content

Trying to teach myself react and stuck on one part... I can't seem to get page specific content to display based on URL using useLocation() -- HELP!

App.js - router displays page on click, yay!

```
    <Router>
        <Routes>
            <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="/project/projectOne" element={<Project />} />
            <Route path="/project/projectTwo" element={<Project />} />
        </Routes>
    </Router>
```

Project.js - Project template serves up the components as expected

```
const Project = () => {
return (
    <div className='content-wrapper'>
        <Scroll />
        <ProjectIntro />
        <ProjectContent />
        <ProjectGrid />
        <Contact />
    </div>
); }; export default Project;
```

ProjectIntro.js - A component trying to serve up the content -- this is where I'm stuck, useLocation() see's the path, but I can't figure out how to show the "projectIntroDetails" based on that path.

```
const projectOne = () => {
  <h1 className='project-intro-heading'>Title Here</h1>,
  <figure className='project-intro-image'>
    <img src={projectImage} alt='placeholder'/>
  </figure> 
}

const projectTwo = () => {
    <h1 className='project-intro-heading'>Title Here</h1>,
    <figure className='project-intro-image'>
        <img src={projectTwoImage} alt='placeholder' />
    </figure>
}


const projectIntroDetails = {
    projectOne: {
        component: <projectOne />
    },
    projectTwo: {
        component: <projectTwo />
    }
}

const ProjectIntro = () => {
    const projectPath = useLocation();
    console.log(projectPath);

    // this is where I need help
    // how do I turn the path into seeing details to render the correct content?
    const projectIntroDetail = projectIntroDetails[projectPath.pathname.split("/project/")];

    return (
        <div className='project-intro'>
            {projectIntroDetail}
        </div>
    );

}; export default ProjectIntro;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a component with a switch statement to determine which child component to render. This method allows you to pass any additional props to the child components.

If you don't need the `<div className='project-intro'>` element, you could also render the switch directly inside your `ProjectIntro` component.

```js
const ProjectOne = () => {
  <h1 className='project-intro-heading'>Title Here</h1>,
  <figure className='project-intro-image'>
    <img src={projectImage} alt='placeholder'/>
  </figure> 
}

const ProjectTwo = () => {
    <h1 className='project-intro-heading'>Title Here</h1>,
    <figure className='project-intro-image'>
        <img src={projectTwoImage} alt='placeholder' />
    </figure>
}

const ProjectIntros = ({ slug, ...props }) => {
    switch(slug) {
        case 'projectOne':
            return <ProjectOne {...props} />;
        case 'projectTwo':
            return <ProjectTwo {...props} />;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

const ProjectIntro = () => {
    const projectPath = useLocation();
    console.log(projectPath);

    return (
        <div className='project-intro'>
            <ProjectIntros slug={projectPath.pathname.split("/")[2]} />
        </div>
    );

}; export default ProjectIntro;
```

Comment: This worked for me! Thank you! The only thing I did need to add was wrap the content of ProjectOne and ProjectTwo in returns and React Fragments.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to use the `useLocation` hook or `pathname` value to handle any conditional rendering logic, that's what the routing components are for.

I would suggest either passing in the correct sub-project component as a prop to be rendered on the correctly matching route, or refactoring the routes to do this in a more "react router" way.

### Passing component down as prop example:

App

```
<Router>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
    <Route
      path="/project/projectOne"
      element={<Project projectIntro={<ProjectOne />} />}
    />
    <Route
      path="/project/projectTwo"
      element={<Project projectIntro={<ProjectTwo />} />}
    />
  </Routes>
</Router>
```

Project

```
const Project = ({ projectIntro }) => {
  return (
    <div className='content-wrapper'>
      <Scroll />
      <div className='project-intro'>
        {projectIntro}
      </div>
      <ProjectContent />
      <ProjectGrid />
      <Contact />
    </div>
  );
};
```

### Using `react-router-dom` to your advantage.

Project

Convert `Project` into a layout component and render the `ProjectOne` and `ProjectTwo` components on nested routes. Layout routes are intended to be used to share common UI elements and layout, and render routed content into an outlet.

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const Project = () => {
  return (
    <div className='content-wrapper'>
      <Scroll />
      <div className='project-intro'>
        <Outlet /> // <-- render nested routes here
      </div>
      <ProjectContent />
      <ProjectGrid />
      <Contact />
    </div>
  );
};
```

App

```
<Router>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
    <Route path="/project" element={<Project />}>
      <Route path="projectOne" element={<ProjectOne />} />
      <Route path="projectTwo" element={<ProjectTwo />} />
    </Route>
  </Routes>
</Router>
```

Comment: Still unsure how this changes the content on a single component. This approach seems that I would have multiple templates and components vs just 1 of each. I may not be fully grasping this. Per the above, I have a single project template with the 3 components ( intro, content and grid ). I want the content in those components to swap based on URL and render on the project template.

Comment: @Rob I think something may be lost in translation. What does "template" mean in this case? Are you referring to the JSX a component returns?  I don't see where multiples of any components would come from. The route is the dynamic part of the equation here, and these refactors leverage that to render the correct content with the correct route path. I stood up a local codesandbox to test this before answering. I'll see if I still have it available, or will recreate it so you have a running example to play with.